# PyTorch Datasets: Converting entire Dataset to NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torchvision

I'm trying to convert the Torchvision MNIST train and test datasets into NumPy arrays but can't find documentation to actually perform the conversion.

My goal would be to take an entire dataset and convert it into a single NumPy array, preferably without iterating through the entire dataset.

I've looked at [How do I turn a Pytorch Dataloader into a numpy array to display image data with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756581/how-do-i-turn-a-pytorch-dataloader-into-a-numpy-array-to-display-image-data-with) but it doesn't address my issue.

So my question is, utilizing `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`, how would I go about converting the datasets (train/test) into two NumPy arrays such that all of the examples are present?

Note: I've left the batch size as the default of 1 for now; I could set it to 60,000 for train and 10,000 for test, but I'd prefer to not use magic numbers of that sort.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the whole train dataset of MNIST images (in total 60000 images, each image of size 1x28x28 array with 1 for color channel) as a numpy array of size (60000, 1, 28, 28)?

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# Transform to normalized Tensors 
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])

train_dataset = datasets.MNIST('./MNIST/', train=True, transform=transform, download=True)
# test_dataset = datasets.MNIST('./MNIST/', train=False, transform=transform, download=True)


train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=len(train_dataset))
# test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=len(test_dataset))

train_dataset_array = next(iter(train_loader))[0].numpy()
# test_dataset_array = next(iter(test_loader))[0].numpy()
```

This is the result:

```
>>> train_dataset_array

array([[[[-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         ...,
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296]]],


       [[[-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         ...,
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296]]],


       [[[-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         ...,
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296]]],


       ...,


       [[[-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         ...,
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296]]],


       [[[-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         ...,
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296]]],


       [[[-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         ...,
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296],
         [-0.42421296, -0.42421296, -0.42421296, ..., -0.42421296,
          -0.42421296, -0.42421296]]]], dtype=float32)
```

**Edit**: You can also get the labels by `next(iter(train_loader))[1].numpy()`. Alternatively you can use `train_dataset.data.numpy()` and `train_dataset.targets.numpy()`, but note that the data will not be transformed by `transform` as is done when using the dataloader.

Comment: I assume that I can use `next(iter(train_loader))[1].numpy()` to get the labels?

Comment: Yes, it gives the corresponding labels.

Answer (score 20):

There is no need to use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` for this task.

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms

train_set = datasets.MNIST('./data', train=True, download=True)
test_set = datasets.MNIST('./data', train=False, download=True)

train_set_array = train_set.data.numpy()
test_set_array = test_set.data.numpy()
```

Note that in this case targets are excluded.

Comment: that's very helpful, but does it give you the labels as well?

Comment: There is no practical reason to include labels in the same matrix of the
data. You can acquire another NumPy matrix of the targets running `train_set_array_targets = train_set.targets.numpy()`

Comment: That is very much true. I was just missing the `data` and `targets` attributes of `Dataset` objects - which I could not seem to find in the documentation for some reason.

Comment: This is because `data` and `targets` are not attributes of the `Dataset` class but of the `MNIST` class that subclasses from `Dataset`. I would direct to the documentation of `MNIST` of `torchvision` package but I don't think there is anything that answers the question asked here.

Comment: this does not include the transform though, where the accepted answer does.