# Pytorch: How to get all data and targets for subsets

Tags: python, pytorch

I used the following code to read the dataset from a specific folder and divide it to train and test subsets. I can get all data and targets for each subset using list comprehension, but it is very slow for large data.
Is there any other fast approach to do this?

```
def train_test_dataset(dataset, test_split=0.20):
    train_idx, test_idx = train_test_split(list(range(len(dataset))), test_size=test_split, stratify=dataset.targets)
    datasets = {}
    train_dataset = Subset(dataset, train_idx)
    test_dataset = Subset(dataset, test_idx)

    return train_dataset, test_dataset


dataset = dset.ImageFolder("/path_to_folder", transform = transform)
    
train_set, test_set = train_test_dataset(dataset)

train_data = [data for data, _ in train_set]
train_labels = [label for _, label in train_set]
```

I've tried this approach using DataLoader, it is better but it also takes some time:
[PyTorch Datasets: Converting entire Dataset to NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897646/pytorch-datasets-converting-entire-dataset-to-numpy)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58487972/6331369) in the link you provided basically defeats the purpose of having a data loader: a data loader is meant to load your data to memory chunk by chunk. This has the clear advantage of not having to load the dataset in its entirety at a given moment.

From your [`ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder) dataset you can split your data with the [`torch.utils.data.random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.random_split) function:

```
>>> def train_test_dataset(dataset, test_split=.2):
...    test_len = int(len(dataset)*test_split)
...    train_len = len(dataset) - test_len 
...    return random_split(dataset, [train_len, test_len])
```

Then you can plug those datasets in separate [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader)s:

```
>>> train_set, test_set = train_test_dataset(dataset)

>>> train_dl = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
>>> test_dl  = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=32 shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew this approach using Torch random_split but I used train_test_split from sklearn to get balanced labels for each subset. I need all data and labels as a NumPy array to do some operations but "DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)", will give a part from data.

Comment: What do you want to perform with the whole array dataset?

Comment: I tried to use this framework to do Federated Learning: https://github.com/adap/flower/tree/main/examples/simulation_pytorch. In the preprocessing, for CIFAR10 dataset: trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(
        root="./data", train=True, download=True, transform=transform
    ). the data and targets can be extracted using trainset.data and np.array(trainset.targets), divide data to a number of partitions using np.array_split. With ImageFolder, there is no direct way to extract them but I can use list comprehension but it is slow, and the kernel sometimes restarts with large data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different way to get data from `torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset` . Subsets are a map to the dataset (like linked lists) ponting to the main dataset. so we first get the indices from the subset then pass it onto dataset:

```
all_dataset.labels[train_dataset.indices]
```

example:

```
class LesionDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
        self.labels =  df.values[...,1:].argmax(axis=1)
        self.images = df.values[...,0]
        .
        .


all_dataset = Datasets.LesionDataset("data/img",
                    "data/img/ALL.csv")
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(all_dataset,[train_size, val_size])
all_dataset.labels[train_dataset.indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach without the need to recreate dataloaders for each subset is to use Subset's **getitem** and **len** methods. Something like:

```
train_data = train_data.__getitem__([i for i in range(0,train_data.__len__())])[0]
train_labels = train_labels.__getitem__([i for i in range(0,train_labels.__len__())])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

For standard image datasets, you can take advantage of 1. the `Subset.dataset` accessor for the overall dataset, 2. the `Subset.indices` index store for the subset, and 3. the `__getitem__` logic of the overall dataset which you can access through `from inspect import getsource; getsource(Subset.dataset.__getitem__)` (where `Subset` should be your actual dataset object).

```
# Setting up the splits
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import random_split
from torch import Generator
from torchvision.datasets import FashionMNIST
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor

BATCH_SIZE = 64

# Download and load the training data
dataset_train = FashionMNIST('./data', download=True, train=True, transform=ToTensor())
print(f'Before splitting the full train set into train and valid: len(dataset_train)={len(dataset_train)}')

size_valid = 5000
size_train = len(dataset_train) - size_valid
dataset_train, dataset_valid = random_split(dataset_train, [size_train, size_valid], generator=Generator().manual_seed(SEED))
print(f'After splitting the full train set into train and valid: len(dataset_train)={len(dataset_train)}, len(dataset_valid)={len(dataset_valid)}')
dataloader_train = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
dataloader_valid = DataLoader(dataset_valid, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)

# Download and load the test data
dataset_test = FashionMNIST('./data', download=True, train=False, transform=ToTensor())
dataloader_test = DataLoader(dataset_test, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)


# Accessing the X and y of a split Subset
X_valid = dataset_valid.dataset.data[dataset_valid.indices]
y_valid = dataset_valid.dataset.targets[dataset_valid.indices].long()
```